# gtag event purchase currency ignored, is always USD

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

On purchase on my ecommerce an event of type 'purchase' is triggered and correctly shown on google analytics dashboard except for the currency.

I've followed this [guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/enhanced-ecommerce#measure_purchases), but also tried to pass parameters with 'transaction' prefix (for example 'transactionCurrency' instead of 'currency'). But I can't see any difference.

Here is how I generate payload for the event and how I send

```
var payload = {
   "transaction_id": tid,                    
   'value': 999.99,                    
   'currency': "EUR", //<--this will be ignored
   'items': items.map(item => ({
       sku: item.sku,
       name: item.description,
       price: item.price,
       quantity: item.qty                        
    }))
};
gtag("event", "purchase", payload)
```

Here is an example of request sent:

https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&_v=j73&a=1550934340&t=event&cu=EUR&_s=2&dl=http%3A%2F%2Fmyhost.svi%2Fordini&ul=it-it&de=UTF-8&dt=ORDINI&sd=24-bit&sr=1920x1080&vp=1912x462&je=0&ec=ecommerce&ea=purchase&ev=45&_u=SCCAAUAL~&jid=&gjid=&cid=252314052.1551781012&tid=UA-xxxxxxxx-x&_gid=xxxxxx.xxxxx&gtm=2ou430&ti=C19000000021&tr=45.19&tt=8.15&ts=5&pa=purchase&pr1nm=item1&pr1pr=1.49&pr1qt=2&pr2nm=item2&pr2pr=21.85&pr2qt=2&z=1998964134

For readability the query string parameters are:

```
{
    "v": "1",
    "_v": "j73",
    "a": "1550934340",
    "t": "event",
    "cu": "EUR",
    "_s": "2",
    "dl": "http%3A%2F%2Fmyhost.svi%2Fordini",
    "ul": "it-it",
    "de": "UTF-8",
    "dt": "ORDINI",
    "sd": "24-bit",
    "sr": "1920x1080",
    "vp": "1912x462",
    "je": "0",
    "ec": "ecommerce",
    "ea": "purchase",
    "ev": "45",
    "_u": "SCCAAUAL~",
    "jid": null,
    "gjid": null,
    "cid": "252314052.1551781012",
    "tid": "UA-xxxxxxxx-x",
    "_gid": "xxxxxx.xxxxx",
    "gtm": "2ou430",
    "ti": "C19000000021",
    "tr": "45.19",
    "tt": "8.15",
    "ts": "5",
    "pa": "purchase",
    "pr1nm": "item1",
    "pr1pr": "1.49",
    "pr1qt": "2",
    "pr2nm": "item2",
    "pr2pr": "21.85",
    "pr2qt": "2",
    "z": "1998964134"
}
```

Currency should be EUR, but this is the result:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Change the ga view's settings in GA's admin to collect ecommerce data in EUR instead of USD.
if you're using one currency in your site then you won't even need to set the EUR currency in gtag.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1010249?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

As @Yoray mentions, change the currency setting in the view settings and that should fix it.

To add to this, if you specify a currency in the hit, you will likely see it as "Local Currency" in custom reports. (I haven't confirmed this with gtag.js).